# Still getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to emit xml in clojure

Tags: xml, clojure

[Full stack trace](https://gist.github.com/1838248)

```
(ns test.xml.emit
  (:use clojure.core)
  (:require [clojure.xml :as xml]))

(defn testemit []
  (xml/emit {:tag :web-app
             :attrs {:xmlns:xsi "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     :xmlns "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                     :xmlns:web "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                     :xsi:schemaLocation "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                     :id "Foo"
                     :version "1.0"},
             :content [{:tag :display-name "FooBar+"}
                       {:tag :listener
                        :attrs {:listener-class "com.example.server.Main"}}
                       {:tag :filter
                        :attrs {:filter-name "guiceFilter"
                                :filter-class "com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter"}}
                       {:tag :filter-mappings
                        :attrs {:filter-name "guiceFilter"
                                {:url-pattern "/*"}}}]}))
```

[In our last episode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299986/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-3-test-xml), [Justin Kramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203655/justin-kramer) was kind enough to explain to me how clojure.xml/emit expects input to be formatted so it can produce usable xml. I'm still getting the same exception, but after I've looked the function over. I wonder if the xmlns:xsi, xmlns:web, and xsi:schemaLocation attributes under the web-app tag might be causing the exception because of the extra colon, but I don't know enough to say for sure. Could someone please show me where I'm going wrong? Thank you for your time and consideration, and have a great day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error has to do with your syntax - you have several maps in your code that have an odd number of forms, maps must have an even number (each key must have a value).  For example, one of your maps:

```
{:tag :display-name "FooBar+"}
```

Has 3 entries, which causes the error you're seeing.  Also note: [What happened to closure.xml/emit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440523/what-happened-to-closure-xml-emit)

HTH,

Kyle